# Why can't I see which methods are being called within the Call Hierarchy window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I very, very rarely have to use the Call Hierarchy window in Visual Studio but today is one of those days.

In this case, I need to explore the depths of the method calls within my application from within a specific method.  Currently, this method only calls four other methods, but I need to hunt down and inspect all calls, to all subsequent methods within this method.

Supposedly, the best way to do this is to right-click on my method name in my code and click on the *View Call Hierarchy* option.  The problem is that the results in the hierarchy window only show me the list of "Calls to ..." the method.  There is no folder containing the "Calls from..." details.  Do I need to configure something or run a process to see the calls from within the method?

A couple of notes, most of the methods being called from within this method are to other methods written in the same class.  There's a moderate chance that as I explore the call tree, I'm going to run into 20-30 unique code paths and possibly 300-500 total lines of code I need to inspect, and potentially more.  I am also only interested in the method calls from within our solution code base.  In fact, from within the hierarchy window, the the drop-down solution is set to "My Solution" which is what I want.  Last, just to be clear in case this makes a difference, this is a C#, .Net Framework 4.6.2 project.

Why am I only seeing calls to this method, and not the subsequent call from this method.  It's my understanding that this tool should be able to do that.

Comment: Are you in a solution mixing .NET Core / .NET Standard / .NET Framework projects? Any interfaces?

Comment: @Dai, there is one inherited interface which contains one method.  It is not called in this class.  The class does inherit from another class, but the immediate methods being called from the one being inspected are not in the base.

Comment: Also, this is a .Net Framework 4.6.2 project. The solution contains a lot of sub projects.  I'm new to this time, but it wouldn't surprise me if some of them are .Net Core, but probably note Standard.  Regardless, those methods, at a minimum, are not being called in my root method I'm trying to inspect.

Comment: What do you mean by “sub-project”?

Comment: @Dai By sub projects, I mean there are other projects within the solution in which this given project depends.  They are "sub projects" within the build tree.  Sorry if that was confusing.